# Request to service error

Tags: android

I have error in my application. My application working with Google Tasks. I am try update my task in google. And get error. I can not understand what could be the problem

```
*do {
    String title_in_cursor = c_AL.getString(nameColIndex);
    String status_in_cursor = c_AL.getString(statusColIndex);
    String note_in_cursor = c_AL.getString(taskColIndex);
    Long data_update_in_cursor = c_AL.getLong(updateIColIndex);
    Log.d(Tag, "2");
    currentTask.setTitle(title_in_cursor);
    currentTask.setStatus(status_in_cursor);
    currentTask.setNotes(note_in_cursor);

    //переводим дату в дататайм
    DateTime dateTime_cursor = new DateTime((Long) me.getValue());//(data_update_in_cursor);

    currentTask.setUpdated(dateTime_cursor);
    //  } while (c_AL.moveToNext());}
    Log.d(Tag, "заапдейтили !!!!!!!!!!"+currentTask.getStatus());
    try {
        Log.d(Tag3, "ПРОАПДЕЙТИЛИ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ В ГУГЛ1 "+currentTask.getTitle()+"__"+dateTime_cursor);
        Log.d(Tag3, "ПРОАПДЕЙТИЛИ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ В ГУГЛ1 "+currentTask.getTitle());
        Task result1 = MainActivity.service.tasks().update("default", currentTask.getId(), currentTask).execute();
        Log.d(Tag3, "ПРОАПДЕЙТИЛИ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ В ГУГЛ2");
        Log.d(Tag3, "ПРОАПДЕЙТИЛИ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ В ГУГЛ2");

        //меняем etag в базе*********************
        SharedPreferences mSettingsList;
        mSettingsList = myCtx.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.LIST_ETAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = mSettingsList.edit();
        editor.putString(MainActivity.ETAG, result1.getEtag());
        editor.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(Tag3, "НЕ УДАЛОСЬ ОБНОВИТЬ В ГУГЛЕ "+e.getMessage());
    }*
```

and get error
logcat

```
08-28 15:49:01.046: D/My(15646): НАЧАЛО<br>
08-28 15:49:01.578: D/My(15646): ПОЛУЧАЕМ ЛИСТЫ1<br>
08-28 15:49:03.718: D/My(15646): ПОЛУЧАЕМ ЛИСТЫ1.1<br>
08-28 15:49:03.851: D/My(15646): ПОЛУЧАЕМ ЛИСТЫ1.2<br>
08-28 15:49:24.265: D/My(15646): ПОЛУЧАЕМ ЛИСТЫ2<br>
08-28 15:49:24.265: D/My(15646): ТЭГИ НЕ РАВНЫ<br>
08-28 15:49:24.265: D/My(15646): ПОЛУЧАЕМ ТАСК1 Kelebro63 Kelebro63's list<br>
08-28 15:49:25.054: D/My(15646): ПОЛУЧАЕМ ТАСК2<br>
08-28 15:49:25.085: D/My(15646): гугл1 =  2013-08-28T10:04:57.000Z'1377684297000/n база = 2013-08-28T14:40:11.422+04:00'1377686411422<br>
08-28 15:49:25.085: D/My(15646): ПРОАПДЕЙТИЛИ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ В ГУГЛ1     Мероприятие__2013-08-28T14:40:11.422+04:00<br>
08-28 15:49:25.085: D/My(15646): ПРОАПДЕЙТИЛИ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ В ГУГЛ1 Мероприятие<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646): НЕ УДАЛОСЬ ОБНОВИТЬ В ГУГЛЕ 400 Bad Request<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646): {<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646):   "code": 400,<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646):   "errors": [<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646):     {<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646):       "domain": "global",<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646):       "message": "Invalid Value",<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646):       "reason": "invalid"<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646):     }<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646):   ],<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646):   "message": "Invalid Value"<br>
08-28 15:49:26.226: D/My(15646): }<br>
```

What I do not correctly? And how it fix?

Comment: Do you have a LogCat output which is not produced by your application?

Comment: As I say: the LogCat above is output produced by your app and not the Android system. Looking closely I see you are getting an exception what you are catching. It's a bad request (error 400). My russian is bad, could you try with just ASCII characters? Maybe it's encoding.